# Getting terrain's height (y) coordinate Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, terrain

I have a terrain as Collada model. I need to add other models on my terrain. For this I think I need to get terrain's height coord (y) by x and z coordinates. Please tell me how can i do that?

```js
var scene, camera, renderer;

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var directionVector = new THREE.Vector3();
        var projector = new THREE.Projector();

        var map =
                {
                    'name': 'map1.dae',
                    'x': -42.1,
                    'y': 54,
                    'z': 0
                }
                ;

        var mapModel;
        var mapLoader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        mapLoader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

        mapLoader.load( map.name, function ( collada ) {
            mapModel = collada.scene;

            mapModel.position.set(map.x,map.z,map.y);//x,z,y- if you think in blender dimensions ;)
            mapModel.rotation.y = 0.002;

            init();
            animate();
        });


        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
                    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
            renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xeeeeee, 1.0 );
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 10000);
            camera.position.set(150,450,300);
            scene.add(camera);
            window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
                var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
                        HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
                renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            });
            window.addEventListener('click',onMouseClick);
            window.addEventListener('mouseMove',onMouseMove);
            var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper( 1580 );
            scene.add(axes);

            var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(1000, 10);
            gridXZ.setColors( new THREE.Color(0xff0000), new THREE.Color(0xff0000) );
            gridXZ.position.set(0,0,0 );
            //red axe 0.00001565217 - CONST в 1 метре, градусов     blue axe 0.000009
            scene.add(gridXZ);

            scene.add(mapModel);


            var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xfffff3, 0.8);
            light.position.set(-300,600,300);
            scene.add(light);
            var sphereSize = 1;
            var pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper( light, sphereSize );
            scene.add( pointLightHelper );
            var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xd7f0ff, 0.2);
            light2.position.set(600,600,200);
            scene.add(light2);
            var sphereSize = 1;
            var pointLightHelper2 = new THREE.PointLightHelper( light2, sphereSize );
            scene.add( pointLightHelper2 );
            var light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
            light3.position.set(300,400,-200);
            scene.add(light3);
            var sphereSize = 1;
            var pointLightHelper3 = new THREE.PointLightHelper( light3, sphereSize );
            scene.add( pointLightHelper3 );
```

[Image][1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZqE4.jpg

Comment: You need a terrain height-map to look into before you can figure out a height. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap

Comment: Okay. I have heightmap in png like this http://jsfiddle.net/4rh073mq/ . And how can I get height in given point?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your heightmap image data, you need to read the pixels in like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

That method will transfer your image to a canvas where you can do imageData lookup to see what each pixel's RGBA value is.

```
var imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

function lookUpPixelColor( imageData, ux, uy ){
  var px = Math.floor( ux * imageWidth );
  var py = Math.floor( uy * imageHeight );
  var index = (uy * imageWidth + ux) * 4;
  if( index < 0 || index >= imageData.data.length ){
    return 0;
  }
  return {
    r: imageData.data[ index ] ,
    g: imageData.data[ index + 1 ],
    b: imageData.data[ index + 2 ]
  };
}
```

This function will now be used to look up any pixel, between a 0 to 1 value.

Then, for every pixel or nth pixel, read the heightmap color value. Assuming a grayscale image with pixel values between 0-255, you can have that many 'levels' of elevation, so 255 would be the tallest peak and 0 would be the lowest possible value.

Now that you've done this, you can loop through each vertex in your plane and solve for the lookup:

```
geometry.vertices.forEach( function( v ){
  var ux = v.x / planeWidth;
  var uy = v.y / planeHeight;

  var rgb = lookUpPixelColor( imageData, ux, uv );
  var height = rgb[ 0 ] / 255;
  var z = height * maxHeight;

  v.z = z;
});
```

This assumes the plane geometry's first vertex is 0,0 and goes to planeWidth/planeHeight. That might not be the case with generated PlaneGeometry from THREE.js, as it may be from -width/2 to width/2

So it would look like:

```
geometry.vertices.forEach( function( v ){
  var ux = (v.x + planeWidth * 0.5) / planeWidth;
  var uy = (v.y + planeHeight * 0.5) / planeHeight;

  var rgb = lookUpPixelColor( imageData, ux, uv );
  var height = rgb[ 0 ] / 255;
  var z = height * maxHeight;

  v.z = z;
});
```

Another quirk is that plane might be generated along XZ instead of XY, so if that's the case then simply replace v.y with v.z during the lookup.

Alternatively, you can use the UVs from faceVertexUVs to do a lookup, where the values are nicely set from 0 to 1

After that's done you'll need to solidify the changes like so:

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```